# How to use Stored Procedure in SqlCE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sql-server-ce

I have just installed **Sql Server Compact Edition**. To my surprise, we can't use stored procedure in sql server CE. Do I have any alternative of Stored Procedure in Sql Server CE.
I am strongly obsessed with stored procedure, I can'nt think of an application without stored procedures.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

**Edit: Can I use Managed Stored Procedures.**

Comment: *"I am strongly obseesed with stored procedure"* - that made me laugh :)

Comment: thats right, I tend to write all my application logic in sp. I don't know if it is a good programming practice or not. Can't help it. :)

Comment: It is a good programming practice depending on the technology and implementation. If you are new to SqlCe you must read Steve Lasker's whitepaper.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SqlCe is a local database for use by an application. There is no need for stored procedures since the database is just a local data store, and the business logic is in the application. It is not an engine. If you need an engine then use SqlExpress or its big brother. **See Steve Lasker's *Comparing SQL Server Express and Compact Editions Whitepaper*** at http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/4/7/A47B7B0E-976D-4F49-B15D-F02ADE638EBE/Compact_Express_Comparison.doc. It explains everything you need to know.

No, you cannot use managed stored procedures. SqlCe is in-process.

Also, you might find *Data Storage Architecture with SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb380177(SQL.90).aspx helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This blog from Steve Lasker describes how you can implement something similar to sprocs on SQL Server Compact: http://blogs.msdn.com/stevelasker/archive/2008/02/11/stored-procedures-and-sql-server-compact-the-great-debate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use inline sql in your application. Use [SqlCeCommand.CommandText Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.commandtext%28VS.80%29.aspx) to specify sql text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what is supported by SQL Server CE, but UDFs can often be substituted for stored procedures. If that doesn't help, try calculated columns and/or indexed views. If those are not available as options, then I think you are stuck with putting the logic in your application.

Comment: None of these things are supported in SQL CE.  Think of it almost as an XML file with enforceable relationships.

Comment: Ah, "think of it as a persisted DataSet" would be more accurate with "writable tables".

Comment: @Aaronaught: and some indexes, I would hope?

Comment: Limited indexes - no include columns, similar to what we got in SQL 2K.  AMissico is right, it's more like a persisted `DataSet` than XML.  It's really the bare minimum you could possibly expect from a database.