# Adding stored procedure in sql server compact, MVC4

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp.net mvc platform and wanted to try something out.
I added a database(SQL server compact) where i have a table with username, address,... as fields. Then i added ADO.net entity data model in my model. 
Of course my stored procedures is empty now. But how do I add new procedures?
when I saw some tutorial they have a folder called stored procedure in server explorer where you can right click and add procedure but mine doesn't have any.
Am I doing something wrong?
Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Compact doesn't support stored procedures.

See [Differences Between SQL Server Compact and SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140.aspx)
(scroll down to **Stored procedures and triggers.**):

> SQL Server Compact 4.0: Not supported

And some questions from Stack Overflow:

- [How to use Stored Procedure in SqlCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078672/how-to-use-stored-procedure-in-sqlce)
- [Does SQL Server Compact Edition supports Stored Procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742341/does-sql-server-compact-edition-supports-stored-procedures)