# Unable to connect to a Local Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, local-database

I am playing with C# and a local database (`An empty SQL Server Compact Edition database for local data`)

But I am unable to connect to the database and get data.

This is what I try:

```
// Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnectionString = Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf
// I guess Visual Studio put it there after I created my database...

using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnectionString)) {
    using(SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = @id", sqlConnection)) {
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
        try {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
            if(reader.Read()) {
                System.Console.WriteLine(reader);
                System.Console.WriteLine(reader["id"]);
                System.Console.WriteLine(reader["name"]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException());
        }
        finally {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

My whole programm hangs for a while, after the pause I get this message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: You sure your connection string is correct?

Comment: You have to be sured that the `named pipes` are turned - "ON"

Comment: @SonerGönül Well, Visual Studio put it there, so I guess it belongs there?

Comment: above error 100% related to connectionstring I add `Database.connectionString` to qustion

Comment: @AnantDabhi Yes, it came from a class Database with a static string.. I changed it in the example to the Property settings made by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am playing with C# and a local database (An empty SQL Server Compact Edition database for
>   local data)

You are using a `Sql Server Compact` file, not a `Sql Server Local DB`

To deal with **Sql Server Compact**, you need to use the `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace, not `System.Data.SqlServer`.

Replace `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, ...

With `SqlceConnection`, `SqlCeCommand`, ...

---

And Stored procedures **are not supported in Sql Server Compact** ([How to use Stored Procedure in SqlCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078672/how-to-use-stored-procedure-in-sqlce)), so `sqlCeCommand.CommandType` can not be `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

You need to use commandType.Text with command parameters.

```
using(SqlCeConnection sqlCeConnection = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnectionString)) {
    using(SqlCeCommand sqlCeCommand = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = @id", sqlCeConnection)) {
        sqlCeCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCeCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
        try {
            sqlCeConnection.Open();
            SqlCeDataReader reader = sqlCeCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
            if(reader.Read()) {
                System.Console.WriteLine(reader);
                System.Console.WriteLine(reader["id"]);
                System.Console.WriteLine(reader["name"]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException());
        }
        finally {
            sqlCeConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So my database type is wrong. What type do I need to have a local database using prepared statements? The Express Edition?

Comment: @Bondye I am not sure I undestand what you are looking for. What do you mean by 'using prepared statements'?

Comment: Uhmm.. Just [Prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement#C.23_ADO.NET) to prevent some injections and overheading.

Comment: @Bondye OK... So just create your Database from Visual Studio or copy the existing Database in your project and let Visual Studio Create typed Dataset and appropriate code. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
```

And then

```
using (SqlCeConnection sqlConnection = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCeCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = @id", sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCeDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(reader);
                System.Console.WriteLine(reader["id"]);
                System.Console.WriteLine(reader["name"]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException());
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```